# EJB serve PDF, cause re-request object belongs to other PDF exception

Tags: java, pdf, itext, ejb, indirect-objects

I am using EJB to serve a pdf that created by iTextPdf 7.0.4 over Internet by call remote business interface.

My EJB server side implement as:

```
@Override
public byte[] renderBillById(String billId) {
    logger.info("rendering bill pdf called in EJB Model.");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
    document.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);

    fetchBillContext(billId);

    document.add(billHeaderTable());
    document.add(billReceiverTable());
    document.add(billBalanceTable());
    document.add(summaryOuterTable());
    document.add(howToPay());
    document.add(notesPara());
    document.add(payOptionsTable());

    document.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

The server implement will generate a PDF and I will need it in byte array format. I tried request the byte array over Web server (call it in web server by using controller to server a JSF page) and request it over remote EJB client (call it over RMI), I got same result as: I can only call this implement once, when I tried call it again, EJB server throws following exception:

```
 com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
```

Details as:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:127)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy306.renderBillById(Unknown Source)
at com.longz.ozssc.web.staff.BillControlBean.viewBillInPdf(BillControlBean.java:191)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:304)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:535)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at com.longz.ozssc.web.staff.misc.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:28)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
```

The server side exception looks like have some Object reference issue.

I tried to found out the similar issue in stack overflow, most of them regarding it is a PdfFont issue, but in my case, I didn't used any PdfFont.

Does anyone else have the problem? if you have. How do you fix it?

Comment: This can pretty much only be a problem in one of the methods you reference in the `document.add` calls, so please share the code for your `billHeaderTable()` and similar methods.

Comment: PdfFont object never be used in my PDF document. That is why I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to [chapter 1](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1) of the iText 7 Building Blocks tutorial. Search for the error message:

> Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.

You will discover that you are:

> attempting to use a `PdfFont` instance that belongs to the PDF that was created the first time...

If you read the chapter, you will learn about the difference between

- The `FontProgram` object, a font object that can be instantiated once and reused every time you create a PDf, and
- The `PdfFont` object, a font object that is unique to each PDF that you create, and that should be instantiated *for every document you create*.

As indicated by [blagae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065017/blagae), the error is somewhere in the `billHeaderTable()`, `billReceiverTable()`,... methods.

Comment: Thanks! Mate. PdfFont object never be used in my PDF document. That is why I am very confused.

Comment: In that case, you are reusing another object you shouldn't reuse. We can't tell you which one, because you don't show us the relevant code.